# .net drop down menu - open new window

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have a search form on our website, that helps you find specific health proviers. It is a .net application which is not my specialty...

```
<select name="ctl00$middleContent$ddlProviderType" 
    onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$middleContent$ddlProviderType\',\'\')', 0)" 
    id="ctl00_middleContent_ddlProviderType"> 

    <option selected="selected" value="Please Select One">Please Select One</option> 
    <option value="Behavioral Health">Behavioral Health</option> 
    <option value="Dental">Dental</option> 
    <option value="Hospital in Idaho">Hospital in Idaho</option> 
    <option value="Medical in Idaho">Medical in Idaho</option> 
    <option value="Hospital/Medical outside of Idaho">Hospital/Medical outside of Idaho</option> 
    <option value="Hospital/Medical outside the U.S.">Hospital/Medical outside the U.S.</option> 
    <option value="Medicare Advantage Behavioral Health">Medicare Advantage Behavioral Health</option> 
    <option value="Medicare Advantage Medical">Medicare Advantage Medical</option> 
    <option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option> 
    <option value="Urgent Care Centers">Urgent Care Centers</option> 
    <option value="Vision">Vision</option> 
</select>
```

One of these select options [Hospital / Medical outside of Idaho] opens a new window using the function:

```
ResponseHelper.Redirect("http://site.example.com", "_blank", "")
```

So in a perfect world, the user would be sent to our sister site, and continue their search there.

This seems to be an issue because it initiates most pop up blockers in browsers today.

So, when this happens, it seems that the users still think they are MY site, and tries to continue utilizing our search form, which does not function because they should on the other site..

What type of function should I be using to open this new tab or new window without flagging a pop up blocker?

OR should I just not open a new window and keep it in the parent window?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you really have no control over what a user does with their browser. That means you need to provide some feedback that the user needs to allow a popup, or figure out a better way to accomplish your goal. For instance, you could use some JavaScript to maybe hide the select and present a link to click with some instructions.

HTH.